# How do I wire a gazebo

Tags: electrical, wiring, outdoor

I just purchased a outdoor pavilion that came with an electrical package. It includes a #12 two wire plus a ground wire going into an electrical box for the on and off switch to run the fan and another #12 two wire plus ground wire going into a GFI outlet box. The GFI outlet should run constant while the switch should run when turned on.
My questions is how to correctly wire this. The power will be running off the GFI outlet.

Comment: The GFI outlet box is part of the gazebo, but not pre-wired to the switch? And the switch IS pre-wired to a (ceiling?) fan? It would help very much if you took a picture of what you have in the gazebo (showing wires/boxes) and what, if anything, you have coming from the house.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the cable going to the switch just requires a feed.

I am not sure how you intend to bring power to the gazebo from the main house, but basically you would wire both 12/2 cables to the #12 feed wire and wire it color for color; white to white, black to black, ground to ground.

The GFI would get wired to the LINE terminals only.

Please comment if you can add any details that might help.

Comment: the wire coming from the home electrical panel is powering the gfi outdoor outlet.

Comment: Where is this GFI? Are you referring to an existing one on your house, or the new one in the gazebo?

Comment: the new one on the gazebo

Comment: Need pics or diagram please.

Comment: So you  have a new cable from the house to the gazebo?